# How can I make a form transparent according to a PNG image?

Tags: delphi, forms, png, transparency, delphi-2010

I have a PNG image that uses transparency (it is actually a circle with gradient effect from black in the middle, to transparent on the margins). I am putting this on a form using `TImage`. I set `TForm1.Color` and the `TForm1.TransparentColorValue` to the same value and `TForm1.TransparentColor:=true`.

Now, when I run the program the gradient part of the image is displayed with the color of the form. What I am looking for is to enable the transparency of the PNG image using the transparent form effect.

What am I doing wrong?
I am using Delphi 2010 Trial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you're trying to create something like a transparent [splashscreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen), if that's the case, you can read these great articles, they describes a nice way to use a transparent png in a delphi form.

- [Alpha Blended Splash Screen in Delphi - Part 1](http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash)
- [Alpha Blended Splash Screen in Delphi - Part 2](http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash2)

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Your settings are wrong. I am doing this (With a bitmap).

The TImage.Transparent should be false.

The Form.TransparentColourValue should be the colour of the part of The TImage that you want to be transparent.

The Form.TransparentColor should be True.

[Edit]
It does not matter what colour the form is if the Image covers it completely