# Transparent form background when using a png image

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I tried to create a transparent form, and put a PNG image in the background.
I tried the "TransparentColor" but I had a bitmap form.
Is there another method?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the AlphaBlend:= true and AlphaBlendValue to an appropiate transparency.

See this article for more details: http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash/
See also this question: [How can I make a form transparent according to a PNG image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558420/how-can-i-make-a-form-transparent-according-to-a-png-image)